# Existence of a Linear Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am working on a linear static optimization problem. I found a solution to the problem. However, I want to formally check the solution existence. I tried some methods but I don't know if it is enough to check those. I will note  below the problem and the methods I tried. I will appreciate your comments.

$\underset {a_i \mbox{or} G_i^L} \max \ \alpha \ln C_i + \beta \ln G_i^L+ \beta \ln G_i^C$

s.to

$C_i=[1-t(f_da_i+(1-f_d))]Y_i$

$G_i^L=f_d\cdot a_i\cdot t\cdot Y_i$

$G_i^C = \sum \limits_{i=1}^n[(1-f_d)t\cdot Y_i]\frac{p_i}{\sum \limits_{i=1}^n p_i}$

where $0<\alpha,\beta,f_d,t,p_i<1$ and $a_i,Y_i >0$.

what I tried is called Inada conditions: checking the limit of the first derivatives w.r.t. $C_i$, $G_i^C$, and $G_i^L$. When that limit goes to infinity the derivatives goes to zero. This satisfies the Inada conditions.
I also checked that this objective function is concave and increasing in $C_i$, $G_i^C$, and $G_i^L$. Second derivatives are positive.

Do I have to check the Weierstrass Theorem? I have a solution to this problem but the substitutable equalities are not compact.